# How to install Umbraco on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-vista, umbraco

i want to learn umbraco,and for start step,i need to know How to install Umbraco on Windows 7?

i found my answer and made this [link](http://s1.picofile.com/file/7560878167/persian.rar.html) for farsi(persian) language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best thing to do is grab [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/), after install click on app gallery and choose umbraco, and that will walk you through it.

Or if you have IIS running you can use the web platform installer(just click on applications and scroll down to umbraco) both of these will install 4.9 you'll have to upgrade to 4.10 manually.