# Packages in uCommerce in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I am  a beginner with **`Umbraco`** and I had installed Umbraco setups and package files from links [**here**](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/ucommerce).

When I started I found that there is no product catalog displaying as you can see in this [**link**](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2010/08/17/Getting+Started+With+UCommerce.aspx). What should I do? Instead of this I have a store catalog is displaying, So I just want to know,

- whether something is missing
- or I have to create product catalog manually
- or store is replacement of my product catalog

Comment: Just right-click the node and press "create", "ucommerce.dk" (documentation link) is just a demo productcatalog

Comment: if your problem about install umbraco look at this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359343/how-to-install-umbraco-on-windows-7

Comment: Have you tried UMBRIACO instead of UMBRACO?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the uCommerce TV videos at http://www.ucommerce.dk/en/support/ucommerce-tv.aspx - they go through installing ucommerce, how to setup a catalogue and then in the marketing video it goes through how orders are stored and using promotions and discounts.  There should be enough there to get you going.

The 4 videos are about 30 minutes long in total - and well worth taking the time to go through.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screen shot you have referred in the tutorial, I would agree "store is replacement of my product catalog". The blog you are referring seems to be bit old (2010).

Refer: http://demo.ucommerce.net/